# Issues with Jquery .post and google chrome on a linux server

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, post

After doing test after test and creating new scripts I have discovered that chrome is having issues with this part of my jquery script:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".subto").click(function() {
    var data = {ramp: ramp, toilet:toilet, door:door, blind:blind,
    dog:dog, assist:assist, ear:ear, lift:lift, park:park, ramped:ramped, star:star
    };
     levelramp(data);
   });


function levelramp(ramp,toilet) {
    var url = "http://youraccessguru.com/sesstest1.php";
    $.post(url, {ramp: ramp},function(data) {
       $("#text").val(data).show();
    });

    }
```

http://youraccessguru.com/sesstest.php
To get the error still depends on how long you take clicking the buttons try it to see. If you ASAP click a picture and submit the script itwill work
but if you press back and wait 30 secs on page then select and click submit the hightlight would have not changed or worked.

The first button doesnt work anyway separate issue just leave unset.

The site works fine in any other browser except Google chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue I see is that you're binding a POST request to a submit button that submits it's own form, and you're not preventing that form from being submitted. So your script does this when you click subto:

1. Fire ajax post to http://youraccessguru.com/sesstest1.php
2. Immediately after that fire regular POST request to http://youraccessguru.com/sesstest.php with no data

Note that these may not even happen in order. I have no idea what number 2 actually does, but my assumption is that it's redirecting you to sesspreview.php if it receives POST data.

So you have 2 choices. If you want to do a page refresh, there's absolutely no need for you to be using an ajax request. If you still want to use ajax, stop the regular form from being submitted, and redirect to sesspreview.php on the ajax complete function.

EG:

```
$(function(){
  $(".subto").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {ramp: ramp, toilet:toilet, door:door, blind:blind, dog:dog, assist:assist, ear:ear, lift:lift, park:park, ramped:ramped, star:star};
    levelramp(data);
  });


  function levelramp(ramp,toilet) {
    var url = "http://youraccessguru.com/sesstest1.php";
    $.post(url, {ramp: ramp}, function(data) {
      window.location.href = "sesspreview.php";
    });
  }
});
```

Of course this depends on how your PHP files are set up and what they are actually doing. I have no idea, so if you're POSTing data to sesspreview.php, this won't work.

EDIT:
Ok, so you continue using AJAX, then regular POST to submit the rest of the data. In this case, submit AJAX first, then wait for ajax response before submitting rest of the form. Give your form an ID, then use code like this:

```
$(function(){
  $(".subto").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {ramp: ramp, toilet:toilet, door:door, blind:blind, dog:dog, assist:assist, ear:ear, lift:lift, park:park, ramped:ramped, star:star};
    levelramp(data);
  });


  function levelramp(ramp,toilet) {
    var url = "http://youraccessguru.com/sesstest1.php";
    $.post(url, {ramp: ramp}, function(data) {
      $('#formID').submit();
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: The submit button is there to to save other fields such as text boxes and validate any input from a user. So disabling this makes thing more difficult.

Comment: Then why not just submit the 'ramp' data along with the rest of the form? Why submit 'ramp' in an ajax post request, then immediately submit the rest of the data in a regular post request?

Comment: The submit button is there to to save other fields such as text boxes and validate any input from a user using php. So disabling this makes things more difficult. I will see if your suggestion helps though. sesstest1 is saving the .post into php sessions so they can then be stored in a mysql data base. Users aren't sent to sesspreview until all fields are validated giving the .POST time to save sessions. Sorry I am not an expert developer. http://www.youraccessguru.com/createnew.php Is the full page. Sesspreview just displays the highlighted pics before being stored in mysql.

Comment: Jquery changes the pictures with ought having the browser refresh

Comment: The issue, which I may not have been clear about, is that you are submitting 2 POST requests one after another. One via AJAX for those buttons, then one via regular POST for the rest of the form. This is bad practice, and may quite possibly be causing issues, as the page might redirect before the AJAX post has had enough time to actually submit. If you absolutely MUST do it this way (you don't), read the update to my answer which I will post in about 1 minute.

Comment: Cheers for helping Christian I will try and get my head around it tomorrow maybe im doing something to complected for my skill level just annoying that it works on my local host in chrome and on my server all browsers accept chrome

Comment: I have fixed the issue by separating the pages first page is just php and then the second small jquery / javascript controlled form this has resolved the issue thank you Christian would have taken me ages without your help

Comment: It's these types of things that make you a better developer! No doubt you've learnt heaps trying to fix this problem!